# Fog/aws gem for IBM Cloud Object Storage is not working

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, fog, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

As Softlayer or IBM Cloud has moved from Swift based Object Storage to S3 based Cloud Object Storage. I am using fog/aws instead of fog/softlayer.

The below is the code:

```
require 'fog/aws'
fog_properties = {
  provider: 'AWS',
  aws_access_key_id: username,
  aws_secret_access_key: api_key
}
@client = Fog::Storage.new(fog_properties)
@client.directories
```

But it failed even with valid key and id.

```
<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.\</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>####</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>####</RequestId><HostId>##</HostId></Error>
```

End Point IBM COS uses is "https://control.cloud-object-storage.cloud.ibm.com/v2/endpoints"

When I tried to use fog alone(require 'fog'). It throws the below error:

`Unable to activate google-api-client-0.23.9, because mime-types-2.99.3 conflicts with mime-types (~> 3.0) (Gem::ConflictError)`

Please suggest how to resolve these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for IBM Cloud Objects Storage

```
properties = {
          region: region,
          endpoint: URI('https://s3.us-south.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud'),
          credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(access_key_id, secret_access_key)
        }
        Aws.config.update(properties)
        @client = Aws::S3::Client.new
```

Properties for the config can also be set as ENV variables.

Below are few basic operations performed on COS.

List all the bucker names

> @client.list_buckets.buckets.map(&:name)

Create Bucket

> @client.create_bucket(bucket: )

Upload a file

> @client.put_object(bucket: , key: , body: )

Download a file

> @client.get_object(bucket: , key: )

Delete a file

> @client.delete_object(bucket: , key: )

Delete a Bucket

> @client.delete_bucket(bucket: )

Answer (score 1):

> https://control.cloud-object-storage.cloud.ibm.com/v2/endpoints"
>   This is not an endpoint but a list of endpoints in JSON.

Choose the endpoint for your bucket location.
For example if your bucket is in us-south the public endpoint is 
https://s3.us-south.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud